# How do i split a single cell content into a same cell?

Tags: excel

For example:
my singular cell is `AMAZON FACEBOOK TWITTER INSTAGRAM`

How do i split a single cell content into a same cell?

my cell:

```
AMAZON 
FACEBOOK
TWITTER
INSTAGRAM
```

I tried to use "Text to column" but its splitting my content into separate columns which I do not want. Please help

Edit: i want the resulting cell to just have the same contents of the cell I am splitting but just separated in a new tab in the same cell. The original cell be will be replaced with the resulting cell. Formula will be great thanks

Comment: What should the resulting "single cell" contain? Just `AMAZON`, or what else? And should it overwrite the original contents or store them in some other cell? How do you want to invoke this? Via a VBA macro, a formula, or something else? Please [edit] to clarify all such points.

Comment: Are you trying to insert carriage returns between the text values so they are on separate lines for each, but still in the same cell?

Comment: Use the `SUBSTITUTE` approach in the linked question; just change the `","` to a space `" "` and make sure that wrap text is turned on for that cell.

Comment: It's still not clear what "separated in a new tab" means. Do you mean you want to replace spaces with tabs, or with newlines, or with something else?